# Unable to insert populated document w/ mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate a document field with referenced document with the right data and saving it to the database. However, I'm unable to insert a document correctly in the database, even though I had successfully saved the document.

```
 **getting-started.js**

 ...
 var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
  });

  var storySchema = mongoose.Schema({
   _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
   title    : String,
   fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
  });

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);


var Johns = new Person({ _id: 15, name: 'Johns', age: 154});
Johns.save(function (err) {
if (err)  {
  console.log('Person Save error! %s', err);
}

var story1 = new Story({
  title: "Once upon a timex??",
  _creator: Johns._id    // assign the _id from the person
 });

story1.save(function (err) {
   if (err) return handleError(err);
   console.log('successful story save! %d', story1._creator);
 });

});

Story
.find({ title: 'Once upon a timex@@@@@@' })
.populate('_creator')
.exec(function (err, story) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log("callback story: ", story);

 story.save(function (err, story) {

   if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('successful save new story w/ populated _creator');
    console.log('The story: creators name: %s', story._creator.name);
    console.log('The story: creator field: %s', story._creator);

  })

});
```

First time executing:

```
>>node getting-started.js
```

Following output:

```
>>opened conn to db
successful story save! 15
opened conn to db
{ fans: [],
   __v: 0,
   _creator: { stories: [], __v: 0, age: 154, name: 'Johns', _id: 15 },
   title: 'Once upon a timex@@@@@@',
   _id: 56244cf796f73380353e803a }
   successful save new story w/ populated _creator
   The story: creators name: Johns
   The story: creator field: { stories: [], __v: 0, age: 154, name: 'Johns',              _id: 15 }
```

However, after commenting out the following code:

```
var Johns = new Person({ _id: 15, name: 'Johns', age: 154});
    Johns.save(function (err) {
    if (err)  {
      console.log('Person Save error! %s', err);
    }

    var story1 = new Story({
      title: "Once upon a timex??",
      _creator: Johns._id    // assign the _id from the person
     });

    story1.save(function (err) {
       if (err) return handleError(err);
       console.log('successful story save! %d', story1._creator);
     });

    });
```

the next time I'm executing

```
Story
    .find({ title: 'Once upon a timex@@@@@@' })
    .exec(function (err, story) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log("callback story: ", story);
    });
```

I'm unable to see my saved Story with the populated field of _creator, it still only has the person _id and not the person object:

```
{ fans: [],
  __v: 0,
  _creator: 15,
  title: 'Once upon a timex@@@@@@'
  _id: 56244cf796f73380353e803a }
```

Comment: Referenced documents are not included automatically. You need to include the populate options in your find query.

Comment: I had done that with: Story
.find({ title: 'Once upon a timex@@@@@@' })
.populate('_creator')
.exec(function (err, story) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log("callback story: ", story);
 in the first lines of code. And was able to retrieve the populated _creator field correctly. However, when I had executed this command without populate option just to see if I could retrieve it again, I was unable to find this record